# button still disabled even if the form is filled

Tags: php, validation, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I tried to create a few tricks for my form "if the form fields is null or empty the submit button should be disabled".

I do this by using livewire but in my case the button it still disabled even if the form fields is filled.

**livewire file :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class ExampleForm extends Component
{
    public $name = '';
    public $email = '';
    public $password = '';
    
    public $disabled = true;
    
    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|min:6',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ];
    
    public function updated($fields)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($fields);
        
        if(!is_null($fields) && !empty($fields)) {
            $this->$disabled = false;
        } else {
            $this->$disabled = true;
        }
    }
    
    public function submitForm()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate();
        
        Example::create($validatedData);
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.example-form');
    }
}
```

**in blade.php**

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <input type="text" wire:model="name">
    @error('name') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <input type="text" wire:model="email">
    @error('email') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
    
    <input type="password" wire:model="password">
    @error('password') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

    <button type="submit" {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer

As per the requirement now, the `disabled` property should be set to false only if all the validation passes for the required fields.

```php
public $disabled = true;

public function updated($fields)
{
   $this->disabled = true; 
   $this->validate(); // this is a blocking call
   $this->disabled = false; // execution will reach this line only if all passes the validation.

}
```

Note that, the `$fields` property passed through only has the currently updated property. so we cannot use it to `validateOnly` method, since it will only validate the passed property.

Comment: it still not working as I expected the button should be still disabled until the all form fields be filled in this case when I add some values just in one field the submit button return normal ??

Comment: I updated my question to see where is the error coming from

Comment: in same time while the user delete the value from the form fields the submit button should return disabled.

Comment: I get this error "Array to string conversion"

Comment: @jhon-jhones sorry for the confusion, it has to be `validate()`. not `validateOnly`

Comment: thank it work just I have simple issue "if the user has update or remove a value from one or more of those fields dynamically the submit button should return Disabled"

Comment: The scenario you explain will still trigger the `updated` hook, so so once the validation fails immediately the button will be disabled.

Comment: the problem now is when I type something in first field it display me the all errors even if I'm just typing in first field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228531/discussion-between-mohamed-irfan-and-jhon-jhones).